# Django rest framework how to serialize a list of strings?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to give a list of strings in postman, for example:

> ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5']

But when it reaches serializer.is_valid() it gives me:

```
"non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
        ]
```

This is my serializer:

```
class URLRequestedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    urls = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
```

How can I make the serializer to except a list of strings?

Comment: Maybe you should show your serializer code?

Comment: Posted my serializer.

Comment: you need to show us more information, at this moment there is now way in knowing what you actually postet. If you only postet an array of strings (consdering your error message) could mean that your post is done wrong because your serializer demands a json like that: `{"urls": ["string1", ...]}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you posted a list instead of a dictionary as JSON in Postman, just as the error message said.

You posted:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5']
```

But you should have posted:

```
{
    "urls": ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"]
}
```

Remember, your serializer defined the field `urls`, you therefore have to send the data to the correct field in your JSON body :)

Answer (score -3):

The string list received from postman is string type in django, try to use `eval` to convert it.

Comment: sry but the error message does not suggest anything like that. at actually says that the posts data does not match the serializers requirements.

Comment: Generally try to avoid `eval`.